# What is my problem with updating data without auto-updating the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, asynchronous

The problem with updating data without auto-updating the page
please help with this, I provide the code below
if possible, tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to avoid it in the future

frontend

```
    async getFavoriteUser(userId: string){
        try {
            const response = await MarketService.getFavoriteProducts(userId);
            const favorites = response.data
            return favorites;
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }

    async deleteFavorite(favoriteId: number, userId: string){
        try {
            await MarketService.deleteFavorite(favoriteId, userId)
            const favorites = await this.getFavoriteUser(userId);
            console.log(favorites);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

backend
product controller

```
    async  getFavoriteProducts(userId) {
        try {
            const currentUser = await UserModel.findById(userId);
            const favoriteProductIds = currentUser.favorites || [];
            const favoriteProducts = await ProductModel.find({ _id: { $in: favoriteProductIds } });
            return favoriteProducts;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
    async deleteFavorite(favoriteId, userId) {
        try{
            const currentUser = await UserModel.findById(userId);
            const favorites = currentUser.favorites || [];

            favorites.splice(favoriteId, 1);
            currentUser.favorites = favorites;
            
            await currentUser.save();
            return favorites
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }
```

I tried to change it useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    store.getFavoriteUser(store.user.id)
        .then((favoritesData) => {
            setFavoriteProducts(favoritesData.favoriteProducts);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Ошибка при получении избранных товаров:", error);
        });
}, [store]);
```

here's how it is output

```
  <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
    Избранные товары
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 2 }}>
    {favoriteProducts.map((product) => (
        <Card key={product._id} sx={{ width: 305, height: 450 }}>
      {product.name}
        <Button size="small" variant="contained" color='error' onClick={() => handleDeleteFavorites(favoriteProducts.indexOf(product))}>
          Удалить
        </Button>
    </Card>
            ))}
        </Box>
  </TabPanel>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.